# if else statement connect to DB unique for logged in user

Tags: sql, pdo

I creating a twitter look a like platform for studying purpose, I have reach to the follow and unfollow part.

I have two buttons, the follow and unfollow button, they both works fine If i press follow it insert session ID and the id of the user i want to follow. If i press unfollow it removes that row.
all good.

I have now added ad if else statement to the buttons so if you press the follow button it changes to unfollow and by pressing the unfollow it changes back to follow.

The problem is that since the if else works depending if the row is empty or not, it gives me back the same results for every logged in user.
Maybe there is a better way to show the buttons ?

This is what I have for now.

```
    <?php foreach(fetch_users($_GET['uid'])as $user){   


    if(empty($user['follow_id'])){ ?> <form action="" method='POST'>
    <button type="submit" class="follow" name="submit" value="<?php echo $user['id'] ?>"/>FOLLOW</button> 
    </form>

<?php }    else{     ?>
    <form action="" method='POST'>
    <button type="submit" class="follow" name="delete" value="<?php echo $user['id'] ?>"/>UNFOLLOW </button> 
    </form>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
    </form>


    </div>
    <?php } ?>


function fetch_users($uid){
global $db;
$query = $db->query("SELECT user.id, user.username, user.email, userdetails.profile_img, following.follow_id
FROM user
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
LEFT JOIN following ON user.id = following.follow_id
WHERE user.id != '{$uid}' ");
$user = array();
while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !==FALSE) { 
$user[] = $row;

}
return $user;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the apparent SQL injection in your code?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes absolutely.

Comment: You could also use `fetchAll()` instead of looping with `fetch()`.  Perhaps check the value of 'follow_id' using `var_dump()` so you can better check.  It should be null when there's no follow_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach(fetch_users($_GET['uid']) as $user): ?>
<?php $butt = $user['follow_id'] ? 'UNFOLLOW' : 'FOLLOW'; ?>
<form method='POST'>
  <button type="submit" class="follow" name="<?=$butt?>" value="<?=$user['id']?>">
    <?=$butt?>
  </button> 
</form>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?
function fetch_users($uid){
    global $db;

    $query = "SELECT user.id, username, email, profile_img, follow_id
              FROM user
              JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
              LEFT JOIN following ON user.id = following.follow_id
              WHERE user.id != ?";
    $stm = $db->prepare($query);
    $stm->execute(array($uid));
    return $stm->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into it. didn't work out of the box. need to se what i need to change. thanks again.

Comment: I were thinking of moving that If logic into query and accidentally removed follow id. edited code

Comment: Mr. I got it work, but the issue with the following and followers remains. Lets say that user 1 is following user 2 and 3 . If i log-in with user 2, it looks like im already following user 3 but in the database there is no connection. well hard to explain :) your solution was anyway better looking than mine

Comment: indeed,  the weirdest is that it works fine wile Im only following 1 user. If I follow more than one user, the changes reflects on the other users. hustling hustling :)

Comment: what is the purpose of this query?

Comment: Its so you can follow users. Lets say the site has 4 users.
When I'm logged in as user 1. I can see the other three users and decide to follow them. If i decide to follow user 2 and 4, In the database the values would be user_id = 1, follow_id = 2 and 4 .
Now when Im following user 2 and 4 with user 1. When Im logging in with lets say user 2, the buttons that you helped me with. shows Follow on user 1 but unfollow on user 4, its like the values from user 1 reflects on the other users. the chooses are not unique for the logged in user.